# How to wrap h1 and follow content in div?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, wrapall

I need to know how to wrap `h1` and follow content in `div`. This is the original structure:

```html
<h1>Title #1</h1>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>

<h1>Title #2</h1>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>
<p>Text</p>

<h1>Title #3</h1>
<p>Text</p>
```

This is the result I want to get :

```html
<div>
  <h1>Title #1</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Title #2</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>

<div>
  <h1>Title #3</h1>
  <p>Text</p>
</div>
```

Comment: @DoryZidon I think he wants to automate the section detection in DOM.

Comment: @Zenith One difference is that it doesn't include the `h1` itself.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Try using `wrapAll` and group the `h1` and all `p` tags

```
$(function () {
    $('h1').each(function () {
        $(this).nextUntil('h1').add(this).wrapAll('<div />');
    });
});
```

**DEMO:** http://jsfiddle.net/zPafK/

or http://jsfiddle.net/zPafK/2/ (added some styles)

Comment: Thank you, fast anwser, I'll give a try rightaway.